# Как использовать три модели в ActiveDataProvider?

Tags: yii2

Есть модель Category
она связана вот так с тремя другими моделями

```
public function getSerials(){
        return $this->hasMany(Serial::className(),['id'=>'id_serial'])->viaTable('fl_cat_serial', ['id_cat' =>'id']);
    }
    public function getFilms(){
        return $this->hasMany(Serial::className(),['id'=>'id_film'])->viaTable('fl_cat_serial', ['id_cat' =>'id']);
    }
    public function getMfilms(){
        return $this->hasMany(Serial::className(),['id'=>'id_mfilm'])->viaTable('fl_cat_serial', ['id_cat' =>'id']);
    }
```

возникла не необходимость использовать три модели вместе для виджета listveiw и засунуть её в провайдер одну я знаю  можно использовать так

```
$category= new Category;
$serialDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' =>$category->getSerials(),
                'pagination'=>[
                    'pageSize'=>60,
                ]
            ]);
```

а вот как использовать три одновременно голову себе сломал пытаюсь решить при помоши join вот так

```
$querys=CatSerial::find()
            ->select('fl_serial.id,fl_serial.name_serial,fl_serial.slug_serial,fl_serial.nesting,fl_film.id,fl_film.name_film,fl_film.slug_film,fl_film.nesting,fl_mfilm.id,fl_mfilm.name_mfilm,fl_mfilm.slug_mfilm,fl_mfilm.nesting')
            ->leftJoin('fl_serial','fl_cat_serial.id_serial = fl_serial.id')
            ->leftJoin('fl_film','fl_cat_serial.id_film = fl_film.id')
            ->leftJoin('fl_mfilm','fl_cat_serial.id_mfilm = fl_mfilm.id ')
            ->where(['id'=>$categoryThe->id])
            ->groupBy('fl_cat_serial.id_serial, fl_cat_serial.id_film,fl_cat_serial.id_mfilm');
```

он мне выдает такую ошибку
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

```
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `fl_serial`.`id`, `fl_serial`.`name_serial`, `fl_serial`.`slug_serial`, `fl_serial`.`nesting`, `fl_film`.`id`, `fl_film`.`name_film`, `fl_film`.`slug_film`, `fl_film`.`nesting`, `fl_mfilm`.`id`, `fl_mfilm`.`name_mfilm`, `fl_mfilm`.`slug_mfilm`, `fl_mfilm`.`nesting` FROM `fl_cat_serial` LEFT JOIN `fl_serial` ON fl_cat_serial.id_serial = fl_serial.id LEFT JOIN `fl_film` ON fl_cat_serial.id_film = fl_film.id LEFT JOIN `fl_mfilm` ON fl_cat_serial.id_mfilm = fl_mfilm.id WHERE `id`=1 GROUP BY `fl_cat_serial`.`id_serial`, `fl_cat_serial`.`id_film`, `fl_cat_serial`.`id_mfilm`) `c`
```

Comment: Прочитай про with. Вернусь домой вечером помогу если не получится у Вас. http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/yii2-join-vernulsja

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade я там поправил ответ поступил по вашему совету но выдало ошибку в обшем смотрите.

Comment: join не нужно. Используйте связи в моделях через hasOne или hasMany в зависимости от задачи и связывайте через with. Например: ->with(['serials'])

Comment: А можете косательно этого кода показать для примера ? не понимаю если честно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял

Можно сделать подобный образом:

```
$ggCarrierRows = GgCarrierProfileRequest::find()->orderBy('id DESC')->all();
$wpCarrierRows = WpCarrierProfileRequest::find()->orderBy('id DESC')->all();
$ggCustomerRows = GgCustomerProfileRequest::find()->orderBy('id DESC')->all();
$wpCustomerRows = WpCustomerProfileRequest::find()->orderBy('id DESC')->all();


$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
  'allModels' => array_merge($ggCarrierRows, $wpCarrierRows, $ggCustomerRows, $wpCustomerRows),

  'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 20,
  ],
]);

return $this->render( 'index' , [
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Правда может быть проблема, если поля не пересекаются, и выводить их в **GridView** может быть проблемно. Однако решить подобное можно через просто условие

```
[
  'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
  'template' => '{view}',
  'buttons' => [
    'view' => function ($url, $model) {
      if('common\models\GgCarrierProfileRequest' === get_class($model))
        return \yii\helpers\Html::a('Посмотр', Url::to(['/profile-requests/gg-carrier-view', 'id' => $model->id]));
      if('common\models\WpCarrierProfileRequest' === get_class($model))
        return \yii\helpers\Html::a('Посмотр', Url::to(['/profile-requests/wp-carrier-view', 'id' => $model->id]));
      if('common\models\GgCustomerProfileRequest' === get_class($model))
        return \yii\helpers\Html::a('Посмотр', Url::to(['/profile-requests/gg-customer-view', 'id' => $model->id]));
      if('common\models\WpCustomerProfileRequest' === get_class($model))
        return \yii\helpers\Html::a('Посмотр', Url::to(['/profile-requests/wp-customer-view', 'id' => $model->id]));
    },
  ],
],
```

Таким образом вы избавляете себя от сложных запросов и гораздо проще кастомизировать таблицу